# Apply text filter to teaser

Tags: input-formats, nodes

I use inline images in my article content type. Currently my Teaser settings strip the HTML tags, leaving me with the text of the image tag, which runs into my article text. I'm reading about [making a custom filter](http://pingv.com/blog/drupal-text-formats-102-developing-custom-filters), but how can I apply the resulting text format only to the Teaser?